# Ionic3 in iOS can't stream coordinates to my API when the app is in the background

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm using Ionic 3 and this cordova plugin [mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) but the app doesn't stream coordinates when it's in the background in iOS.

It works in Android, iOS emulator but not in a real iPhone. Also, the `url` option stops streaming after 1s

**My code so far:**

```
/**
 *
 * @param {boolean} status
 * @param {number} stepOn
 */
private registerCoords(status: boolean, stepOn?: number): void {
    let step: number = stepOn ? stepOn : 1;

    if (!STATIC.GEO_INTERVAL && status) {
        STATIC.GEO_INTERVAL = setInterval((() => {
            this.currentCoords = this.geolocationService.getCoords();
            if (!this.isNetWork) {
                this.functions.f_alertToast('Network connection lost', 0);

                return this.registerCoords(false);
            }

            if (!this.currentCoords && !this.isProcessPicture) {
                this.geoLocationEvent = false;
                this.isGeoLocation = false;
                console.warn('[HomePage] registerCoords() -> setInterval() [GPS connection lost!!]');
            }
            else if (this.currentCoords) {
                this.geoLocationEvent = true;
                this.isGeoLocation = true;
            }

            this.saveCoords(this.currentCoords, step);
            step = 1;
        }).bind(this), STATIC.GEO_TIMEOUT);

        this.finishLoad();
    }

    if (status === false) {
        clearInterval(STATIC.GEO_INTERVAL);
        STATIC.GEO_INTERVAL = null;
        this.checkGeolocation();
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="2.3.5">
    <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
    <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
    <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
    <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
    <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
    <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="$PACKAGE_NAME" />
    <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.3">
    <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="..." />
</plugin>
```

**package.json**

```
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "4.9.0",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "2.4.3",
"cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": "2.3.5",
```

Comment: Seeing the plugin, there seems to be an opened issue related to your problem: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/issues/524 did you check this already?

Comment: Side note: the plugin you're using is a fork of another plugin that is now migrated to this plugin instead: https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt . You may also want to check this, though it's not free, apparently.

Comment: @briosheje I'm using "Always authorization" and still doesn't work. Will try the other plugin

Comment: it looks like it's a "common" issue of the plugin. Many other are experiencing the same issue you are describing, apparently.